# .htaccess force server to add a trailing slash, except for links with extensions

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I had an error in the past "404 Not Found" when writing www.website.com/page instead of www.website.com/page/

And I corrected it by adding the following code to the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

But now, it didn't render an xml page, because a trailing slash was added to the link
Example: www.website.com/post-sitemap.xml/

I want to prevent any errors in the future by simply adding a command on the .htaccess so it doesn't add the slash to links ending with: .html .php .xml .css ... etc

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```